# What about this DDoS question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question titled 'DDoS and Shared Hosting'](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/78021/50427) was closed as "too broad".

What should I change (e.g. what should I add, and/or what should I remove) in order to make this a question which you consider reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Limit yourself to one question.  You have a bullet list of multiple questions.    The question is too broad because it is asking too many things.

Your sub-question "Is there any commercially-available service..." is off-topic here.   Questions that ask for third party resources, software, or services attract too much spam and self promotion.  Take that one out for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How about the last bullet point, i.e. "Should I look for a different web host, or what: what must I do if I want better availability? Or should I tell my boss that this is already approximately as good as it gets, state of the art?" Is that OK if I remove the previous two bullet points, or is that still too broad?

Comment: That one is verging into opinion based territory.   I'd stick with the "What level of service should I expect from a host when they suffer a DDoS attack?"  You can add more to the question without asking so many questions.   "My current host suffered a DDoS attack.  My site suffered downtime because of it. I'm thinking about finding a new host because of this."

Comment: I rewrote it. Is it still too broad? Should I delete option 2 altogether? I included option 2 because it seems to me theoretically more reliable than option 1 could ever be, but maybe it's useless if there's some reason why it's unfeasible? I don't know why it might be unfeasible but [this comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/292625/can-you-set-a-backup-ip-for-your-server-in-dns#comment276412_292629) suggests that it is not (or was not then) a preferred/easy/obvious solution.

Comment: It was still too broad.  I edited it for you to make it comply with our guidelines and re-opened it. It no longer asks everything you were asking before.   You could ask other questions if you still have problems.